# How to change fragment shader color between renders?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am struggling with coding this simple boat scene. It is a homework question but I am truly stumped. I have two models which I upload. One is a cube which has a fragment shader to color itself blue. The second is a boat which has a fragment shader to color itself white. When I use two different shaders the boat model is invisible. With much struggling and searching

I am stumped so I am trying plan B which is find a way to change the colors of a fragment shader between rendering the two objects, but I can't find out how to do so.

```
void render() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //BOAT START
    //Rocks the ship, simulating ocean rocking
    if(shiprocker < 5000){
        shiprocker++;
        theta += 0.00002f;
    }
    if(shiprocker ==15000){
        shiprocker = -5000;
    }
    if(shiprocker > 4999){
        shiprocker++;
        theta -= 0.00002f;
    }
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);  

    boat_model->mR = glm::rotate(            
        glm::mat4( 1.0f ),
        glm::degrees( theta ),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
        );

    glm::mat4 mtx_trans = glm::translate(
        glm::mat4(1.0f),
        glm::vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f, -15.0f )
        );

    boat_model->mM =  mtx_trans * boat_model->mR;        
    boat_model->render();
    //BOAT END


    //OCEAN CUBE START
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);  

    glm::mat4 mtx_trans_cube = glm::translate(
        glm::mat4( 1.0f ),
        glm::vec3( -20.0f, -50.0f, -50.0f ) 
        );

    plane_model->mM = glm::scale(  
        mtx_trans_cube,              
        glm::vec3( 10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f )
        );

    //gl_FragColor = (0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f , 1.0f); wont compile
    //glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); changes nothing

    camera->set_uniform_view_perspective( plane_model->shader->program_ID );
    plane_model->render();
    //OCEAN CUBE END


    glutSwapBuffers();
}



int main (int argc, char** argv) {

    // Initialize GLUT
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA|GLUT_DEPTH|GLUT_MULTISAMPLE | GLUT_RGB);


    //WINDOW SETTINGS
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
    glutCreateWindow("SailBoat");

    //PASSIVE FUNCS
    glutReshapeFunc(change_viewport);
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutIdleFunc( animate );

    //ERROR CHECK
    if (GLEW_OK != glewInit()) {
        exit(1);
    }

    //Clear color used for sky tones.
    glClearColor(0.529f, 0.807f, .98f, 1.0f);
    glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable (GL_MULTISAMPLE);

    Shader* boatShader = new Shader( VERTEX_SHADER, BOAT_FRAGMENT_SHADER );
    Shader* cubeShader = new Shader( VERTEX_SHADER, CUBE_FRAGMENT_SHADER );

    //BOAT
    boat_model = new Model(boatShader); 
    load_model(boat_model ,MODEL_BOAT_FILENAME);
    boat_model->upload_2_server();


    //OCEAN CUBE
    plane_model = new Model( boatShader );
    load_model(plane_model ,MODEL_PLANE_FILENAME);
    plane_model->upload_2_server();

    // Set up the camera 
    theta = 0.0f;
    shiprocker = 0;
    camera = new FPSCamera(60.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 10000.0f, true);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

FRAGMENT SHADER

```
#version 150

in vec4 color;
out vec4 fColor;

void main () {
    fColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5);
```

}

Comment: Have you tried using GLSL uniform variables?

Comment: In your `Model.render` function, are you calling `Shader->use` or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use uniform variables in GLSL to pass in values in between render calls. Set up your fragment shader like so:

```
#version 150

in vec4 color;
out vec4 fColor;
uniform vec3 boatColor;

void main () {
    fColor = vec4(boatColor, 0.5);
}
```

And in your C++ code:

```
glUseProgram(program); // Where program is your shader program
GLint uniform = glGetUniformLocation(program, "boatColor"); // since boatColor is what we called the uniform variable in our fragment shader
glUniform3f(uniform, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Set the boatColor variable to be a solid red
// Render your first boat
glUniform3f(uniform, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set the second boat to be a solid blue
// Render your second boat
glUseProgram(0);
```

And that should work nicely. If anyone else here has a better way, please let me know; I'm relatively new to GLSL.

Comment: That looks like a perfectly good approach, _Mr Chemo_. If you had a lot of relatively small objects, and care about the best possible performance, you could also consider using attributes instead of uniforms. It's slightly more complex because they go to the vertex shader first, and then need to be passed along to the fragment shader. But depending on platform and driver efficiency, updating uniforms can be moderately expensive, while updating attributes might be more efficient. You would want to benchmark it, though.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got everything running just right now. I was having so much trouble communicating between the c++ code and the shader, but you've helped me a ton!

Comment: @JellyJay Glad to help! In that case, please accept my answer. :)